# Bootstrap Modal not scrollable when opened with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap modal set up but I populate it with data retrieved via the jQuery ajax function. If the modal is opened using the following code, then it opens fine, and is scrollable.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-xs" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editContact"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></button>
```

However, as I populate it with data, I call a JavaScript function to do the ajax call, and populate it with the data. The function is called on button click, like so:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-xs" onclick="open_contact(2);"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></button>
```

Which calls the follow JavaScript function:

```
function open_contact(id)
{
    $.post("contacts/get",
    {
        // Posts relevant details to show the right content
    },
    function(data, status) {
        // Code here to check for valid response etc
        $('#editContact').modal('show');
    });
}
```

This JavaScript works fine - it throws no error and it retrieves the data fine. It also opens the modal fine. However, when the modal is opened with the JavaScript rather than with the first button (with the data-target), the whole browser window scrolls rather than just the modal.

For reference, the modal opening tags:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="editContact" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="editContact" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
```

Does anyone have any suggestions please?

**Edit**

I should just clarify that my issue isn't the fact that I don't have scroll bars. The issue I'm having is when I scroll using the mouse wheel for example, the page behind the modal will scroll, but the modal doesn't move. Therefore, any text hidden from view in the modal, never comes into view.

Comment: Running local tests, that isn't the behaviour I'm getting... Let me make a Bootply example to show you. http://www.bootply.com/UqiWHuyG7w Notice the scrollbar appears on the right of the screen in both examples.

Comment: Do you suggest that there is something else that's interfering with it? And if so, what could it be, because that is my layout

Comment: To be honest, I think what is happening is the intended functionality of Bootstrap's Modals. The scrollbar never appears in the modal itself, always outside. I don't know if maybe you're using an older version of bootstrap (since I don't recognize some of the syntax, like `<i class...>`), but maybe upgrading would fix it. But again, I'm not too sure there's actually an error here.

Comment: Thanks Tim. I've amended the question as I don't think I was clear. However, the <i> class is actually font awesome rather than bootstrap

Comment: Ok, that makes sense now. Question, do you have a `modal-body` in there?

Comment: Regarding your edit: again, that doesn't sound like an issue. Why would you want to scroll the page behind the modal, if you have the modal displayed? The modal is the focus of the user attention when displayed, not the page behind it.

Comment: @TimLewis Does it? Sorry I'm missing something...

Comment: @Dura, I don't have any more time today, work's over... I can check again when I get home... Sorry.

Comment: Tim - Yes, I haven't included it to keep the sample short. Dura - my issue is the opposite. The page behind currently scrolls and the modal does not. I want the modal to be the focus. It is the focus when it is opened using the first button, but not when opened with jQuery.

Comment: Have you tried [Bootlint](https://github.com/twbs/bootlint)Ing your page?

Answer (score 1):

I think the comments to your question are right, *not* showing the scrollbar is the intended behaviour.

Class `modal-open` gets added to the HTML `body` when you show the modal, and removed when you hide it.

This makes the scrollbar disappear since the bootstrap css says

```
.modal-open {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

To achieve what you want - showing the scrollbar - you can override the native css by specifying

```
.modal-open {
    overflow: scroll;
}
```

in your own css file.

Comment: Maybe I weren't clear with my question, but the scroll bars aren't the issue. My page is big enough to have scroll bars anyway, but when I scroll normally (with mouse for example), the main page itself scrolls, and the modal stays where it is (e.g. text on the modal out of view never comes into view). Hopefully that makes sense!

Comment: @Parker1090 If you think your question is not clear enough, please edit it. Not everyone will read the comment above.